# How to work with time offset in a postgresql statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with postgresql statement and the time difference.

Due to the time difference I have problems when querying between midnight and 3 am. What is the (code-wise) cheapest way to solve this?

My solution simply takes too long

error-prone between 0 and 3 o'clock

```
select p.n, p.e,s."name" , g."time", p."date" 
from l 
    join g on l.g_id = g.id 
    join p on l.p_id = p.id 
    join s on l.s_id = s.id 
where p."date" = current_date and p."time" >current_time- '3 hour'::interval
```

Takes 4 times longer than previous:

```
select p.n, p.e, s."name" , g."time", p."date" 
from l 
    join g on l.g_id = g.id 
    join p on l.p_id = p.id 
    join s on l.s_id = s.id 
where p."date" + p."time" >(current_date+current_time)- '3 hour'::interval
```

Comment: That is not surprising. But you didn't give us `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, nor do we know what indexes there are on `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a fixed time window and the date and time fields are already different below is more straight forward.  (single table example)

```
drop TABLE if exists data;

create table data
(
    rid integer,
    adate   date,
    atime   time
);

insert into data (rid, adate, atime) values
(1, '2020-07-15', '23:59:59'),
(2, '2020-07-16', '00:00:00'),
(3, '2020-07-16', '01:00:00'),
(4, '2020-07-16', '03:00:00'),
(5, '2020-07-16', '03:00:01'),
(6, '2020-07-16', '04:00:00')
;

select rid, adate, atime from data
 where adate = '2020-07-16'
   and atime <= time '03:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

The first query can take advantage of optimizations on `p.date` and `p.time`, such as an index on `p(date, time)`.

The second cannot take advantage of such an index.  Nor does it have accurate statistics for the sum of the two columns.

So, the execution plans are likely to be different, explaining the difference in performance.